# cellForRowAtIndex path is not being called

Tags: ios, swift

The function **cellForRowAtIndexPath** is not being called even on first view or after table entry.This is a code snippet of a to-do list application.

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet var tblTasks: UITableView!

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return taskMgr.tasks.count
    }

    **//THIS FUNCTION IS NOT BEING CALLED.
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //Check if Function is being called or not
        println("hello")
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Default Tasks")
        cell.textLabel!.text=taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text=taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }**

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if(editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete)
        {
            taskMgr.tasks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tblTasks.reloadData()
        }

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        println(taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row])
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tblTasks.delegate = self
        tblTasks.dataSource = self
        tblTasks.reloadData()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: The more important question is whether `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` getting called. If not, you may have neglected to set the `dataSource` and `delegate` of the table view. Or you neglected to set the base class for the whole scene in IB. If it is called, what value is it returning? If it returns zero, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` won't get called.

Comment: Debug and find the value of `taskMgr.tasks.count` if this array is empty it will also not be count (cause you tell the tableview that there are no rows in the tableview)

Comment: @Rob the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection gets called once but after adding an item, it Doesn't.

Comment: @milo526 the value is empty initially but after adding an item the count is indeed incrmented but tableView:numberOfRowsInSection doesn't get called afterwards

Comment: after adding an item you need to reload the tableview for new item to show up

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.3 .... just tried it on a friend's Xcode 6.1.1 ...works pretty well there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved Using this method found while surfing:

You can do this:

In your tableView Controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "loadList:",name:"load", object: nil)
    }

   func loadList(notification: NSNotification){
        //load data here
        self.tblTasks.reloadData()
    }
```

Then in the other ViewController :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("load", object: nil)
```